# blocks within blocks and variable capture

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

When I have a method performing the work from a callback and the method itself references the class's properties, is that considered a leak with the way blocks are captured?

```
@interface ClassA
- (void)performClassAWorkItem1:(void (^)(NSArray *list, NSError *err)block;
- (void)performClassAWorkItem2:(void (^)(NSString *string, NSError *err)block;
@end

@interface ClassB
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ClassA *classA;
@end

@implementation ClassB

- (void)manipulateFirstThing {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self.classA performClassAWorkItem1:^(NSArray *list, NSError *err) {
        [weakSelf manipulateSecondThing:list];
    }];
}

- (void)manipulateSecondThing:(NSArray *)list {
    for (NSString *str in list) {
        // Is this causing the name property to get captured, causing a leak?
        if ([str isEqual:self.name]) {  
            NSLog(@"Ok this worked!")
            // Is accessing self.classA like this ok?
            [self.classA performClassAWorkItem2:^(NSString *string, NSError *error) {
            // If I access self.name here, is this also a leak?
            }];
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: There is no block within a block in the code you've supplied.

Comment: Asked it too quickly. Updated question.

Comment: @WillamHill: There is still no block within a block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that doesn't cause `self.name` to be leaked.  When you send the `manipulateSecontThing:` selector, a strong reference to weakSelf is passed as the first implicit argument (and the selector `_cmd` is the second).

Comment: So the usage of self.<property> in the method is the captured weak self version?

Comment: Typically block retain cycles occur then the block is a property and thus retained by self. Then the block retains self via a method call of an ivar reference.

Comment: @WillamHill: If you use `self`, then it will capture `self` from the enclosing local scope (the body of `manipulateSecondThing:`).

Answer (score 2):

Since neither of the blocks are retained by self there is no retain cycle. Each block is retained by the method it is in and when the methods complete they release their blocks.